# Gatsby.js importing *.obj file error - Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:1)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, 3d, gatsby, viewer

I want to import obj file and render it using [react-3d-viewer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-3d-viewer).
I created viewer component and sample_03.obj file exist in the same component folder.
When I try to next line, it occurs compile error.

## component.js

```
import object3 from './sample_03.obj';
```

## compile error

```
 ERROR #98123  WEBPACK

Generating development JavaScript bundle failed

Unexpected character ' ' (1:1)

File: src\components\ObjectViewer\sample_03.obj:1:1

failed Re-building development bundle - 0.865s
[      ]   0.000 s0/3 0  Writing page-data.json files to publ
ERROR in ./src/components/ObjectViewer/sample_03.obj 1:1    
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type,
currently no loaders are configured to process this file. Seehttps://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> # Blender v2.74 (sub 0) OBJ File:
'tigre_sumatra_sketchfab.blend'
| # www.blender.org
| mtllib tigre_sumatra_sketchfab.mtl
 @ ./src/components/ObjectViewer/index.js 8:0-38
 @ ./src/pages/contact.tsx?export=head 10:0-54 186:41-53     
 @ ./.cache/_this_is_virtual_fs_path_/$virtual/async-requires.js
21:45-163
 @ ./.cache/app.js 16:0-52 30:87-34:1 33:29-42 36:29-42 30:0-34:2

develop compiled with 1 error
```

I want to import sample_03.obj file and render it properly without error.